# How to average all coordinates within a given distance in a vectorized way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I did find a way to calculate the center coordinate of a cluster of points. However, my method is quite slow when the number of initial coordinates is increased (I have about 100 000 coordinates).

The bottleneck is the for-loop in the code. I tried to remove it by using np.apply_along_axis, but discovered that this is nothing more than a hidden python-loop.

Is it possible to detect and average out various sized clusters of too close points in a vectorized way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
np.random.seed(7)
max_distance=1

#Create random points
points = np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3,3],[3,4],[5,5],[8,8],[10,10],[8,6],[6,5]])

#Create trees and detect the points and neighbours which needs to be fused
tree = cKDTree(points)
rows_to_fuse = np.array(list(tree.query_pairs(r=max_distance))).astype('uint64')

#Split the points and neighbours into two groups
points_to_fuse = points[rows_to_fuse[:,0], :2]
neighbours = points[rows_to_fuse[:,1], :2]

#get unique points_to_fuse
nonduplicate_points = np.ascontiguousarray(points_to_fuse)
unique_points = np.unique(nonduplicate_points.view([('', nonduplicate_points.dtype)]\
                                                 *nonduplicate_points.shape[1]))
unique_points = unique_points.view(nonduplicate_points.dtype).reshape(\
                                          (unique_points.shape[0],\
                                           nonduplicate_points.shape[1]))
#Empty array to store fused points
fused_points = np.empty((len(unique_points), 2))

####BOTTLENECK LOOP####
for i, point in enumerate(unique_points):
    #Detect all locations where a unique point occurs
    locs=np.where(np.logical_and((points_to_fuse[:,0] == point[0]), (points_to_fuse[:,1]==point[1])))
    #Select all neighbours on these locations take the average
    fused_points[i,:] = (np.average(np.hstack((point[0],neighbours[locs,0][0]))),np.average(np.hstack((point[1],neighbours[locs,1][0]))))

#Get original points that didn't need to be fused
points_without_fuse = np.delete(points, np.unique(rows_to_fuse.reshape((1, -1))), axis=0)

#Stack result
points = np.row_stack((points_without_fuse, fused_points))
```

**Expected output**

```
>>> points
array([[  8.        ,   8.        ],
       [ 10.        ,  10.        ],
       [  8.        ,   6.        ],
       [  1.33333333,   1.33333333],
       [  3.        ,   3.5       ],
       [  5.5       ,   5.        ]])
```

**EDIT 1: Example of 1 loop with desired result**

*Step 1*: Create variables for the loop

```
#outside loop
points_to_fuse = np.array([[100,100],[101,101],[100,100]])
neighbours = np.array([[103,105],[109,701],[99,100]])
unique_points = np.array([[100,100],[101,101]])

#inside loop
point = np.array([100,100])
i = 0
```

*Step 2*: Detect all locations where a unique point occurs in the points_to_fuse array

```
locs=np.where(np.logical_and((points_to_fuse[:,0] == point[0]), (points_to_fuse[:,1]==point[1])))
>>> (array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)
```

*Step 3*: Create an array of the point and the neighbouring points at these locations and calculate the average

```
array_of_points = np.column_stack((np.hstack((point[0],neighbours[locs,0][0])),np.hstack((point[1],neighbours[locs,1][0]))))
>>> array([[100, 100],
           [103, 105],
           [ 99, 100]])
fused_points[i, :] = np.average(array_of_points, 0)
>>> array([ 100.66666667,  101.66666667])
```

*Loop output after a complete run*:

```
>>> print(fused_points)
>>> array([[ 100.66666667,  101.66666667],
           [ 105.        ,  401.        ]])
```

Comment: Can you describe in words what the critical operation is doing, and perhaps show an example with hard-coded minimal input and output?

Comment: Sure, I added the example to my question. The loop basically loops over all the unique points that have to be averaged out. For every point it selects the detected neighbours and calculates the center coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck is not the loop which is necessary since all the neighborhoods have not the same size.

The pitfall is the `points_to_fuse[:,0] == point[0]` in the loop which trig a quadratic complexity. you can avoid that by sorting the points, by index.

An example to do that, even it doesn't solve the whole problem (after the generation of `rows_to_fuse`):

```
sorter=np.lexsort(rows_to_fuse.T)
sorted_points=rows_to_fuse[sorter]
uniques,counts=np.unique(sorted_points[:,1],return_counts=True)
indices=counts.cumsum()
neighbourhood=np.split(sorted_points,indices)[:-1]
means=[(points[ne[:,0]].sum(axis=0)+points[ne[0,1]])/(len(ne)+1) \
for ne in neighbourhood] # a simple python loop.
# + manage unfused points.
```

An other improvement is to compute means with `numba` if you want to speed the code, but the complexity is now ~ optimal I think.

Comment: Indeed, that was the bottleneck. A very nice and fast approach. Although the output is not exactly the same, I think I can work with this. Thanks a lot!